# How to filter particular day hours with minutes data as store into Array as Single Index among multiple indexes in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, filter, nsarray

I have two arrays. In that Arrays one array storing some numbers like 1,3,4, etc.

```
totalFilterActionArray : ["1", "21", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "20", "1", "1", "1", "1", "6", "1", "9", "1", "13"]
```

Other one is storing time stamp like for each hour has some time stamp like

```
totalFilterActionTimeArray : ["11:22:34", "11:36:05", "11:38:00", "11:38:17", "11:38:31", "11:38:46", "11:40:51", "11:40:56", "11:41:25", "12:02:46", "12:12:59", "12:13:06", "12:58:46", "12:58:48", "12:59:39", "12:59:48", "01:00:02", "01:00:07", "01:00:21"]
```

So, above two arrays indexes count is same.

Now, I want to for each particular hour of totalFilterActionArray data, like suppose above totalFilterActionTimeArray 11'o clock has intervals like "11:22:34", "11:36:05", I want to take these all 11'o clock data average (sum of them divided by count of indexes) from totalFilterActionArray. Then next hour 12'o clock, etc goes on till for 24 hours suppose.

And if there is suppose in that time array if any hour missing like 2'o clock or '4'o clock, I want to add that hour data as value as 0 (zero value).

> Here I want out put array is like newAppactionsarray is ["total 11'o
>   clock appactions data sum/total 11'o clock time intervals count,"total
>   12'o clock appactions data sum/total 12'o clock time intervals count,
>   till 24 hours];

I don't want time here, I want only appactionsarray data.

```
These data should store into other array, Because I am showing those data each hour as single line in some graph.
```

For this I tried following

```
for(index , value) in totalFilterActionTimeArray.enumerated() {

 value.components(separatedBy: ":").first! 

   someotherArray.append(totalFilterActionArray[index])

   }
```

But, The above logic is not working as we expected, its getting all the data from all hours, how can we filter for each hour which are available in that array data like I explained in above.

I hope I explained my issue here completely, if anyone facing issue regarding this understand, please make comment below, I can explain more.

Can anyone suggest me, how can we achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: `totalFilterActionTimeArray` has a missing starting `"` in front of  `12:58:46` is that a typo or part of the question?

Comment: its type mistake, edited.

Comment: Can you please elaborate these lines of your question ? "I want to take these indexes average from totalFilterActionArray. So, complete 11'o clock data is single index. like that I want to take 1+21+ till complete all data of 11'o s single data like sum or average of that data, then next hour 12'o clock, etc goes on till for 24 hours."

Comment: I have to take all each hour of data into single number like suppose 11'o clock has multiple time intervals, so, AppActionsarray has for 11'o clock multiple entries. So, I want to take all 11'o clock indexes from AppActionsArray sum then 12'o clock data, etc. Clear?

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely understand your problem but i hope this solution is helpFull for you..

```
var totalFilterActionArray = ["1", "21", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1"]
var totalFilterActionTimeArray = ["11:22:34", "11:36:05", "11:38:00", "11:38:17", "11:38:31", "11:38:46", "11:40:51", "11:40:56", "11:41:25"]
var gettingArray = [String]()
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureView()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func configureView() {
    var array = [String]()
    var arrayInt = [Int]()
    var filterAction = 0

    for i in 1...24 {
        for(index , value) in totalFilterActionTimeArray.enumerated() {
            let time = value.components(separatedBy: ":").first!
            if Int(time)! <= i &&  Int(time)! > (i - 1) {
                filterAction = filterAction + Int(totalFilterActionArray[index])!
                arrayInt.append(Int(totalFilterActionArray[index])!)
                array.append(value)
            }

        }
//            print(arrayInt)
//            print(array)
        if array.count == 0 {
            gettingArray.append(0)
        } else {
            gettingArray.append(gettingTotalTime(array, filterActionValue: filterAction))
        }
        arrayInt.removeAll()
        array.removeAll()
        filterAction = 0
    }
    print(gettingArray)
}

func gettingTotalTime(_ array: [String], filterActionValue: Int) -> Int 
 {
     return filterActionValue/array.count
 }
```